# How to count the number of lines of code in all files in a directory and its sub directories

Tags: c#, count, lines-of-code

How to count the number of lines of code in all files in a directory and its subdirectories. eg. I have a directory which has many subdirectories and each subdirectory has many files and I want to count that how many lines of code is written in these files.

I tried many ways but it gives a different result. Can anyone help me to this using C#?

Directory looks like this:

```
root
   |---view
   |       |--view1.js
   |       |--view2.js
   |---controller
   |            |--cont1.js
   |            |--cont2.js
   |----model
            |--model.js
            |--model.js
```

I want to give the root path and it returns the total number of lines of codes of all files.

Comment: So you have already tried many ways, Could you please share the code that gives to the approximate output

Comment: Unless you are writing C# code to do this, this is not a programming question and thus is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you are writing C# code to do this and need help with that C# code, you need to include a good [mcve] showing your C# code, and a clear, detailed explanation of what that code does, what you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you are having trouble with.

Comment: (And this isn't a programming question, consider installing a POSIX toolset and using `wc` and `find`, to count the lines in each .cs file in a recursive directory tree.)

Comment: post what you've got and we'll go from there. Should be relatively straightforward but I'm not going to write it for you but I am willing to help with what you've got

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static object GetFilesLineCount(string directory, string searchPattern = "*.*")
    {
        if (directory == null || !System.IO.Directory.Exists(directory))
        {
            return null;
        }


        var filesResults = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, searchPattern, System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                        .Select(file => new
                                        {
                                            FilePath = file,
                                            TotalLines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(file).Count()
                                        }).ToList();
        return filesResults;
    }
```

Return type object I'm using anonymous object on .Select.

Comment: Nice solution. Note that in C# 7 you could return a tuple instead of an anonymous type here.

Comment: @EricLippert I was working when I wrote it,I  thought he can figure out rest of it. I would write extension method and return IEnumerable<Tuple<string,int>> .